# Swift3: Casting UIViewController Subclass Fails

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, swift3

I have a ViewController (`BViewController`) that's inheriting from another `UIViewController` Subclass (`AViewController`). (The reason I want to do this is I'm reusing the same view in storyboard 3+ times for different screens.)

When I call:

```
let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AViewController") as! BViewController
        self.show(vc, sender: self)
```

I get this error:

```
Could not cast value of type 'test.AViewController' (0x10d08b478) to 'test.BViewController' (0x10d08b3f0).
```

Here are my subclasses, they have nothing in them.

```
class AViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

-

```
class BViewController: AViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

**The class in Storyboard is set to `AViewController` because I'm trying to share `IBOutlets` across all children without recreating the views. There is only one `View Controller Scene` in my `UIStoryboard`.**

Comment: You cannot cast your view controller to `BViewController` (subclass of `AViewController` or not) if you set the class to `AViewController` in the storyboard.

Comment: B is A, but A isn't B, meaning you can cast B to A, but not A to B.

Comment: I unset the class and now I get: Could not cast value of type 'UIViewController' (0x10260c718) to 'test.BViewController' (0x1009bf3f0).

Comment: @Mercurial does this mean there isn't really a way to share the storyboard views from one parent? If I don't set the UIViewController class then I can't access the shared IBOutlets that will be common to all subclasses

Comment: @arooo I don't think so. Storyboards are used to project view controller flows. If you need reusability, move your view to a nib and set your ViewController as a file owner. That way you'll be able to use it with multiple controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the answer in this thread, it isn't possible to reuse a single UIViewController Scene with multiple subclasses with UIStoryBoard. It is however possible with nib files.

[How to use single storyboard uiviewcontroller for multiple subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14111572/how-to-use-single-storyboard-uiviewcontroller-for-multiple-subclass)

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't put the right view controller identifier:

```
let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BViewController") as! BViewController
self.show(vc, sender: self)
```

(BViewController instead of AViewController)

**EDIT**:
Here's an example: I have a SignupVC view controller in my storyboard, but its storyboard ID is "signup_vc"

[image]

Comment: The identifier is AViewController because that's the parent– all subsequent subclasses that subclass AViewController (CViewController, DViewController) use the single UIViewController with the identifier AViewController to share the IBOutlets

Comment: Still, I think you should put BViewController as storyboard identifier on your second view controller and AViewController on your first.

Comment: They can have different storyboard IDs, even if one is the parent of this other. The storyboard ID (that you put in your storyboard) is not the class name.

Comment: What would I put as the identifier for a CViewController that shares the same ViewController in Storyboard?

Comment: Your "AViewController" is the class name, but its storyboard ID can be "a_vc" for example. It's the same for your other vcs.

Comment: But I only have one View Controller Scene– I'm trying to reuse the Storyboard Scene (to share the IBOutlets)- I'm deliberately trying to avoid creating multiple Scenes.

Comment: Ok I see. Unfortunately I don't think you can do it that way. You should do the opposite, meaning 3 vcs on your storyboard and one class AViewController they all inherit.

Comment: Yeah– I was hoping to avoid that; it's a bunch of very similar views with just string an image changes.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know other way :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your view controller's class to BViewController in your storyboard